# Extraer datos de una página web sin usar curl php

Tags: php, ajax

Encontré unas formas de extraer datos de otra página que funcionan con AJAX para cargar el contenido. Por lo que es imposible usar PHP o específicamente curl.

Mi problema es que no logro entender bien la manera de lograrlo. Les dejo los códigos:

```html
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://ycapi.org/iframe/?v=6YzGOq42zLk", false);
  xmlhttp.send();
  var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'enlace:' + data + '';
</script>
<div id='demo' />
```

Ejemplo 2:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.7.2/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>j</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    YUI().use('yql', function(Y) {
      Y.YQL('select * from data.html.cssselect where url="https://ycapi.org/iframe/?v=6YzGOq42zLk" and css="buttons", function(response) {
        var html = response.query.results.results.div.download.content; document.getElementById('muestra').innerHTML = html;
      });
    });
  </script>
  <div id="muestra"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Me pregunto por qué no funcionan.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada la pregunta es algo pobre. Sobre cómo funcionan: ¿qué es lo que no entiendes? Y sobre si funcionan o no, ¿qué mensajes ves en la consola de JS?

Comment: Si te entiendo que no llama mucho la atencion . y en la consola no da ningun dato . si visitas esta pagina https://ycapi.org/iframe/?v=6YzGOq42zLk  y revisas el bottom Download veras que lo que nesecito extraer es este enlace https://omp.ymcdn.cc/f79f9b8d29eaee3b875d45f5e8b5a111/6YzGOq42zLk

Comment: He puesto los códigos como ejecutables. Ahí podrás ver que **los dos dan errores que se pueden ver en la consola de JS**: el primero presenta un problema de [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), el segundo presenta un problema de HTTPS/HTTP, pero una vez resuelto (p.e. usando la misma librería desde un [cdn](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/yui/3.7.2/yui/yui-min.js)) el error de sintaxis "Invalid or unexpected token" (porque te faltan unas comillas).

Comment: Entonces ninguno de los dos códigos son viables para extraer el enlace . Para mi la mejor opción era curl php  pero la pagina carga el enlace usando ajax

Comment: ¿La página desde la que realizas las peticiones es en http o https?

Comment: la pagina es http

Comment: El segundo método te debe funcionar bien una vez corregidos algunos errores, porque realmente lo que estarías haciendo es llamar a una página que hace curl por ti y te devuelve los resultados :P. Deja que haga pruebas con http a ver qué puede ser.

Comment: Vale gracias  por tu tiempo

Comment: malas noticias: Yahoo cambió los términos de uso de YUI/YQL (el método usado en el segundo ejemplo) y parece que ya no permite leer el HTML de una URL.

Comment: Que lastima entonces no se puede de ningún método para extraer contenido de una pagina que cargue los datos usando ajax

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿qué es exactamente lo que quieres, y qué es lo que puedes usar? (ponlo en la pregunta) Porque seguramente puedes encontrar un servicio equivalente que haga algo parecido

Comment: Normalmente me gusta aprender algunos ejemplos de como usar esos métodos alternativos a Curl . y ya que con curl no pude obtener la información me dio curiosidad por encontrar otro método . pero esa pagina solo te da la oportunidad de descargar un .mp3 de youtube

Comment: Este tipo de operaciones se hacen hoy día por medio de una API. ¿Los sitios a los que quieres acceder no ofrecen la información que quieres por medio de alguna API?

Comment: Si es verdad pero gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como bien explica [Alvaro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/250/alvaro-montoro) esos dos métodos no funcionan por un tema de control de acceso.

Como menciona [Delcio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/78536/delcio-manuel-polanco-padilla) leer el contenido de una página web y extraer su contenido se conoce como "scraping".

**Nota:**
Si bien el scraping de por si no suele ser considerado ilegal, la mayoría de las veces va en contra de los términos de uso del sitio/servicio web. Si hay un API usar el api, si hay RSS usar rss.

Dicho esto, "escrapear" contenido dinámico sólo con php es bastante complicado, hay que simular ser un navegador web con todos sus chiches: VM javascript, parser HTML, render HTML, sesiones, eventos, etc.

Por lo tanto, y para no reinventar la rueda, vamos a usar herramientas de QA y testeo:

- Headless Chrome : un navegador sin GUI https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome
- Puppeteer : una libreria Node para controlar al headless Chrome https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer
- Node : entorno de ejecución de javascript basado en motor V8 https://nodejs.org/es/
- Rialto : librería/paquete para manejar recursos de Node desde PHP https://github.com/extractr-io/rialto/
- PuPHPeteer : wrapper/bridge implementación de puppeter para PHP https://github.com/extractr-io/puphpeteer

Requiere:
PHP >=7.1, Node >= 8, Composer >= 0.2.2, SO de 64bits 
(testeado en Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS x86_64)

Se puede instalar todo por separado (para un clean install entre dependencias y parches calculale 600mb), o si ya tenes Node 8, PHP 7.1 (CLI) y Composer:

```
composer require extractr-io/puphpeteer
npm install @extractr-io/puphpeteer
```

test.php

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use ExtractrIo\Puphpeteer\Puppeteer;
use ExtractrIo\Rialto\Data\JsFunction;

$puppeteer = new Puppeteer;

echo "le damos cuerda al Cromo ".PHP_EOL;

$browser = $puppeteer->launch();
$page = $browser->newPage();
$page->goto('https://ycapi.org/iframe/?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ',
            ['waitUntil' => 'networkidle2']);
$page->screenshot(['path' => 'asimeveoantes.png']);

echo "espera ";
for ($i=6;$i>0;$i--) :
  sleep(1);
  echo $i;
endfor;
echo " ya casi".PHP_EOL;
$page->screenshot(['path' => 'asimeveodespues.png']);

$enlace = $page->evaluate(JsFunction::create("
    h = document.querySelectorAll('a[id=download]')[0].href;
    return {
        href : h,
    };
"));

printf('Enlace: %s', print_r($enlace, true));

$browser->close();
echo "asemo cURL ".PHP_EOL;

$url = $enlace['href'];
$options = array(
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION => 'progreso',
  CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS => false,
  CURLOPT_FILE    => fopen("clickme.mp3", 'w'),
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT =>  28800,
  CURLOPT_URL     => $url
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

function progreso($resource,$download_size, $downloaded, $upload_size, $uploaded)
{
    if ($download_size > 0)
         echo (($downloaded / $download_size  * 100)%10)==0?".":"";
}

echo "listo".PHP_EOL;
```

1. creamos una instancia de navegador via el titiritero
2. le decimos que vaya a la dirección web
3. tomamos una captura de pantalla para ver cómo se ve
4. esperamos un rato a que el sitio haga sus cosas
5. tomamos otra captura de pantalla para ver la diferencia
6. ejecutamos un javascript en el contexto de la página
7. hacemos algo con la info extraída

**Nota/Advertencia/Disclaimer**

El código es provisto con fines educativos y a manera de prueba de concepto.

- El dominio de ejemplo utiliza variables de sesión y una url temporal para acceder al recurso, esto es práctica estándar.
- También es práctica estándar monitorear las peticiones de red para evitar abusos, así que no te extrañe que luego de N intentos recibas un captcha, o te bloqueen la IP (o grupos de ip si rotas proxies, vpns o accedes via tor).
- Simples cambios en el HTML de la página o el Javascript harán fallar la extracción, de ahí que esta sea una metodología útil para detectar cambios no intencionales derivados del código en automatización de QA.

Answer (score 6):

Tienes la posibilidad de usar http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/

Un ejemplo sencillo sería:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://ycapi.org/iframe/?v=6YzGOq42zLk',
    ['auth' => ['user', 'pass']
]);
echo $res->getStatusCode();
echo $res->getBody();
```

Y también tienes la posibilidad de usar file_get_contents (http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php) que sería más o menos así:

```
$pagina_inicio = file_get_contents('https://ycapi.org/iframe/?v=6YzGOq42zLk');
echo $pagina_inicio;
```

**Actualización**:

Se me acaba de ocurrir otra forma para capturar la página como si navegaras realmente. Se trataría de implementar un bot en javascript en la propia cónsola del inspector de elementos del navegador. Entonces he buscado un poco y no he inventado nada, como suele ocurrir.

Te pongo un ejemplo muy básico, supón que quieres realizar una búsqueda en google, por ejemplo, "bot scrap javascript"; abre google, pega el texto en el buscador y abre el inspector de elementos del navegador, ve a la cónsola y escribe $("#[ID BOTÓN BUSCAR]").click(); y esto realizará la búsqueda. Es decir, puedes acceder a jQuery y javascript desde la cónsola, entonces haz tu script en ella.

Nota: Evidentemente es un proceso manual, por ejemplo, en dónde pone [ID BOTÓN BUSCAR] tienes que poner el ID del botón del buscador de google y éste es dinámico, entonces tienes que o bien buscarlo cada vez, o acceder a él de otra forma, por ejemplo con nth-child(x), pero cuando tengas el script, solo tendrás que abrir el navegador (se puede automatizar), ir a la web (lo mismo) y pegar tu bot script que incluso puede realizar peticiones ajax con información.

Comment: Gracias pero no es posible usar php para extraer este enlace : 
https://omp.ymcdn.cc/f79f9b8d29eaee3b875d45f5e8b5a111/6YzGOq42zLk por que ese enlace aparece luego de que la pagina realiza la petición por ajax por eso buscaba una manera diferente de file_get_contents(); o curl();

Comment: Cuando yo entro en ese enlace, no veo lo que dices, ¿puedes detallar un poco más los pasos de lo que quieres descargar? me refiero navegando, dudo que no se pueda en php y concretamente en curl

Comment: He añadido una forma alternativa de hacerlo, es más manual, pero como tampoco sabemos que buscas exactamente pues igual te vale.

Answer (score 4):

El primer método intenta leer el contenido de la página web cargándola a través de un objeto [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) (xhr) que se usa para obtener información de una URL sin tener que recargar la página completa.

El problema por el que no funciona, es que las peticiones sólo pueden realizarse al el mismo dominio desde el que se ejecuta el código (debe coincidir dominio, protocolo, etc) y ese no es el caso (al menos no desde este sitio). Por eso cuando lo ejecutes el código obtendrás un mensaje como este en la consola de JavaScript:

> Failed to load https://ycapi.org/iframe/?v=6YzGOq42zLk: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

```html
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://ycapi.org/iframe/?v=6YzGOq42zLk", false);
  xmlhttp.send();
  var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'enlace:' + data + '';
</script>
<div id='demo' />
```

Sí funcionaría y se podrían ejecutar sin problemas si se implementara un sistema de [control de acceso HTTP (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) en el servidor de destino (pero no sé si es tuyo).

---

El segundo método que presentas está basado en [YUI](https://yuilibrary.com/) y [YQL](https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/yql/) (Yahoo! Query Language), que es un lenguaje parecido a SQL y que te permite realizar consultas y obtener datos a través de diferentes servicios.

El código presenta varios errores que hace que no funcione. Por ejemplo: la consulta no está bien encapsulada en comillas simples (tiene de apertura pero no de cierre) por lo que recibirás un error "Invalid or unexpected token". Eso se puede solucionar fácilmente.

Luego la consulta parece que está intentando leer el CSS de los botones (no soy experto en YQL y puedo estar leyéndola mal, así que no me hagas mucho caso) y no el código HTML de la URL que le pasas como parámetro. Para leer el HTML la consulta sería algo como:

```
select * from html where url="https://ycapi.org/iframe/?v=6YzGOq42zLk"
```

Por lo que el código quedaría así con esas dos correcciones:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/yui/3.7.2/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>j</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    YUI().use('yql', function(Y) {
      Y.YQL('select * from html where url="https://ycapi.org/iframe/?v=6YzGOq42zLk"', function(response) {
        var html = response.query.results.results.div.download.content; document.getElementById('muestra').innerHTML = html;
      });
    });
  </script>
  <div id="muestra"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Con esto, la petición funciona pero el resultado no devuelve nada, tan sólo  un mensaje de error: la tabla html ya no está soportada y por eso no devuelve el código HTML de la URL pedida. Algo que no se puede ver bien en este snippet (porque muestra un error de https/http, pero que sí puedes ver en este [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvuxofbo/17/)).

> html table is no longer supported. See https://policies.yahoo.com/us/en/yahoo/terms/product-atos/yql/index.htm for YQL Terms of Use

Comment: Mira yo ejecuto este script  <script>//<![CDATA[ 
       
//Show IP address my mybloggertricks.com 
        
var hideloader = document.getElementById("loaderip"); 
        
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {  var myip = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 
 hideloader.style.display='none';     } 

}; 

xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.freegeoip.net/json/", true); 
xmlhttp.send();   
//]]></script>       desde una pagina web http  y funciona bien para obtener los datos

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions Eso es porque la [página que se está pidiendo](http://www.freegeoip.net/json/) permite peticiones desde otros dominios (el enlace a CORS de la primera parte de mi respuesta tiene una explicación sobre esto).

Comment: Ya entiendo bueno vale gracias por la aglaracion

Comment: Alvaro, discupla mi intromisión pero si puedo hacerte una pregunta... ¿cómo que usas snipped para código que no funciona tal cuál? lo pregunto porque he estado editando preguntas de usuarios y borrando snipped a favor de los 4 espacios, igual tengo que dejar de hacerlo, no sé.

Comment: @track3r Tienes razón en que no siempre hay que ponerlos como snippet pero, en este caso en particular, tenerlos como ejecutables es útil porque son ejemplos completos que permiten ver en la consola de JS el error que hace que no funcionen. En otros casos, tener código como snippet no tiene sentido porque no va a proporcionar ninguna ventaja (p.e. cuando es código PHP o cuando es HTML/JS incompleto) y sólo añade ruido.

Answer (score 3):

> Algunos agregadores de noticias aprovechan los iframes para mostrar
>   sitios bajo su propio dominio y evitar que los usuarios se vayan, el
>   mismo Google lo hace con su buscador de imágenes y nos es raro
>   encontrar webmasters que abusen de esta técnica en beneficio propio

Aqui te muestro un ejemplo de como puedes extraer datos (webscraping) de una web utilizando la libreria [php-simple-html-dom-parser](https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser) desde PHP :

**Ejemplo:**

```
   <?php
    include_once('./simple_html_dom.php');

    // Create DOM from URL or file
    $html = file_get_html('https://ycapi.org/iframe/?v=6YzGOq42zLk');

    echo $html;

    ?>
```

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el problema es el mismo de los anteriores, el iframe carga jquery que hace un ajax a un php que devuelve un hash temporal (no directamente sino a través de un javascript también temporal) y este hash es el que arma la url final para descarga. se mantiene la restricción cors y la necesidad de ejecutar el javascript que genera el hash

Comment: Si explicas correctamente lo que quieres, se puede hacer con curl y con cualquier otro método que te han recomendado como respuestas, el problema es que tu intentas acceder directamente a una función que requiere varios pasos. Es decir, se trata de un problema de implementación y estructura, no del método de acceso.

Comment: @aloMalbarez lo que intentas lo he intentado varias veces incluso de diferentes maneras, por seguridad los servidores bloquean el renderizado de sus paginas  he agregado la respuesta a mi solucion.

Comment: Eso ocurre igual Usando Curl() . por eso no es viable usando php