# Editar la pagina rescatada con curl antes de ejecutarla con curl_exec

Tags: php, curl

Ok chicos Les explico estoy conectándome con curl a mi pagina del banco, ingresa perfectamente, pero cuando me ejecuta la pagina como lo hace en mi servidor local, los hipervinculos los busca en mi servidor local algo así href="/HB/frontEnd/css/styleInterno.css", y como obviamente no están no me lo ejecuta y por tanto las funciones JS que necesito que funcionen para que me permita descargar el estado de cuenta o hacer una transferencia mediante un script .js no me funcionan, la idea que tengo en mente es editar dotas esas direcciones por las direcciones completas algo asi https://banfanbenlinea.banfanb.com.ve/HB//frontEnd/css/styleInterno.css" para que esto me pueda funcionar, quise meter la respuesta $ch en file($ch) para leerlo linea a linea y hacer un str_Replace pero no me funciono si alguien tiene una idea como hacer esto y me pudiese ayudar, aquí les pongo mi código

```
<?php //curl coneccion al banco

function loginBanfanb(){  

$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) 
Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)"; 
$cookies = getcwd() . "/cookies.txt";

$ch = curl_init("https://banfanbenlinea.banfanb.com.ve/HB/AppServN.EBK");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 
"https://banfanbenlinea.banfanb.com.ve/HB/frontEnd/loginNatural.jsp");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"inciar_tpo=&intento=1&vacio=vacio&tempUserid=******&userid=60385496465674&passw dnew=******&passwdHidden=%123456789");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
}

loginBanfanb();

?>
```

Comment: chicos ya encontré la manera de hacer lo que buscaba ya les pongo el código pero al entrar me genera un error que igual no me permite conseguir el resultado final deseado no se si se podrá hacer mejor con mas llamadas curl aquí el código

Comment: curlear una sesión es medio complicado fijate si esta forma te sirve : https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158204/81450

Comment: El problema es que aunque descargues los archivos no podras interpretar ni el CSS ni scripts JS. Di deseas automatizar el acceso a la pagina deberias usar algo como selenium, que se parece mas a una navegacion automatizada. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590360/how-to-use-selenium-with-php

Answer (score 0):

chicos ya encontré la manera de hacer lo que buscaba ya les pongo el código pero al entrar me genera un error que igual no me permite conseguir el resultado final deseado no se si se podrá hacer mejor con mas llamadas curl aquí el código

```
<?php //curl coneccion al banco
function loginBanfanb(){  

$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4) 
Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)"; 
$cookies = getcwd() . "/cookies.txt";

$ch = curl_init("https://banfanbenlinea.banfanb.com.ve/HB/AppServN.EBK");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 
"https://banfanbenlinea.banfanb.com.ve/HB/frontEnd/loginNatural.jsp");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"inciar_tpo=&intento=1&vacio=vacio&tempUserid=******&userid=602154185481&passwdnew=******&passwdHidden=5145151");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//curl_exec($ch);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result !== false) { //funciono ?
 //echo "Descarga correcta.";
 $result = str_replace('/HB', 
"https://banfanbenlinea.banfanb.com.ve/HB",$result);
 //file_put_contents("lista.m3u", $result);
 echo $result;
}

curl_close($ch);
}

loginBanfanb();

?>
```

Comment: me genera este error: java.lang.NullPointerException