# ¿Cómo ocultar ID de video de YouTube en PHP?

Tags: php, html

Estoy incrustando un video en mi Web, lo que quiero es que no se muestro el ID del video, vi un ejemplo con imágenes y es correcto, pero estoy tratando de replicarlo con un video pero al parecer el link del video no es correcto.

Este es el link del video donde que tome de referencia se oculta la URL de imágenes.[Video ocultar URL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNZiwYW9ALg&t=807s)

Este es mi código PHP:

index.php

```
<?php
$videos = [


  'ererewrfeerer' => 'RNZiwYW9ALg',
  'ererewrfeerssssssssser' => 'RNZiwYW9ALg'

];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>dddd</title>
</head>
<body>

  <?php foreach($videos as $key => $value): ?>

<img src="imgs.php?h=<?= $key ?>" >
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videos.php?h=<?= $key ?>" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

  <?php endforeach;   ?>

</body>
</html>
```

videos.php:

```
<?php

$videos = [

  'ererewrfeerer' => 'RNZiwYW9ALg',
  'ererewrfeerssssssssser' => 'RNZiwYW9ALg'

];


$filehash = $_GET['h'];
$filename = $videos[$filehash];
$video = $filename;

readfile($video)


?>
```

El objetivo de esto es llamar un campo de una Base de datos y ponerle la capa de otro campo, que eso se muestre en el DOM.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: el truco de las imágenes funciona porque las mismas están en el mismo servidor y se pueden leer con `readfile` en el caso de un video de youtube podes llegar a obtener la url del archivo de video ( mp4 ) desde el source del player en el iframe pero no vas a poder descargarlo "normalmente" debido a restricciones cors 1/

Comment: hay sitios que permiten extraer audio o video de youtube ( tendrás que chequear la legalidad de crear una copia local para servir como propia ) hay un ejemplo de descargar audio ( mp3 ) en https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158204/81450 que ignoro si seguirá funcionando pero te puede dar una pista de lo que implica 2/

Comment: si los videos son tuyos fijate las opciones de privacidad en tu cuenta de youtube que hay varias alternativas para el embed 3/-

Comment: Gracias por responder, los estare revisando